# Is there a generic way to save an image shown in a buffer?

Tags: org-mode, elfeed

Emacs can show inline images in different buffers, e.g. in org, elfeed, mu4e, gnus, etc. Is there a generic way to save such an image to a file?

I know some mode have specific functions do that. Most mail readers that show inline image attachments also have a way to save the attachment. But elfeed does not, as far as I know and org-mode does neither.

Comment: For Org mode, inline images are overlays on links, where the content of the overlay comes from a file. So you don't need to save anything: the file where the image is stored already exists: it was created when you first called `org-toggle-inline-images` or equivalent. Put your cursor on the image, do `C-u C-x =` and you'll be able to see the link (and therefore be able to get to the file). Whether the other programs you mention work the same way I don't know, but if they do, it should be possible to get to the file in a generic way through the `display` property of the overlay.

Comment: @NickD Is this also true for images representing rendered LaTex formulas?

Comment: If you are talking about [LaTeX fragments](https://orgmode.org/org.html#LaTeX-fragments) in Org mode, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Org mode, inline images are overlays on links, where the content of the overlay comes from a file. So you don't need to save anything: the file where the image is stored already exists: it was created when you first called org-toggle-inline-images or equivalent. Put your cursor on the image, do `C-u C-x =` and you'll be able to see the link (and therefore be able to get to the file). Whether the other programs you mention work the same way I don't know, but if they do, it should be possible to get to the file in a generic way through the display property of the overlay.

Assuming that all the programs you mention show inline images as overlays with a `display` property, you can get the file of the image with

```el
(get-char-property pos 'display)
```

where `pos` is the buffer position of the overlay; e.g. you can move your cursor on the image and use `(point)` for the position.

You can learn about `get-char-property` in the usual way: `C-h f get-char-property` and get more information from the Emacs Lisp Reference manual: the section [Examining text properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Examining-Properties.html) describes the function and refers to the [Overlays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html) section; in particular, the [Overlay Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html) section describes all such properties, including the `display` property, and the section [The 'display' property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Property.html) describes the property in greater detail.

Comment: This is was the missing part. Thank you. To make it user friendly, I need to wrap this in a function that can save the in-memory image to some generated file system path.